# Ng update is not working in old node versions

Tags: angular, angularjs

I am upgrading angular 7 to 15 for my project.I am doing it 1 by one .but i have to do it manually.my ng update is not working in any condition.its saying you are using node version 12.13.0 please update it to latest node 18.x .
But now I am upgrading angular 8 to 9.if I update node 18 angular version will not support for sure.
Did a lots of research but couldn't find a proper answer that how can I make ng update work in Lower node versions?

Comment: I would suggest to use try this package which is help you to choose particular versions of the package `yarn upgrade-interactive`

Answer (score 0):

i recommend using the NVM package manager while upgrading to each version changing node version relatively

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).